# How to make text go next line when about to overlap an element

Tags: css

So I've got something like this in the `index.html` file

```
<div id = "quote">
quote text
</div>

<div id = "text">
text
</div>
```

And I have to format it in such a way that it will look something like this
 [image]

The text with the black background being the `quote` div .

Literally spent my whole day googling and trying some ideas but to no avail.

Later edit: I can't put the `quote` div inside the `text` one.

I've tried something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VKYwD/8/) but to no avail

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, especially what you've tried so far so that answerers don't repeat what you've already rejected. Also include any restrictions you may have (as indicated in the comment to the given answer).

Answer (score 1):

`float` is the CSS property you're looking for. You can read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Floats

```
#quote {
  float: left;
}
```

Here's an example

```css
#quote {
  float: left;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
<div id="quote">quote</div>
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
```

Comment: Ok, but keep in mind I can't modify the `index.html` file, and the quote will have to be just around the middle of the page; so I'd probably have to use `top: ...` or something for quote, which will result in overlapping

Comment: @Hansewl if you're hoping someone will help you with those details, you don't have these details in your post. Please update your post with your actual requirements, real code, and provide a demo for us with what you've tried. Otherwise we're going to waste one another's time with stuff that won't work for you.

Comment: You are right, my bad, should have mentioned that, just edited my post. Should've made it more clear that the html file layout can't change; as in I can't put the quote div inside the text one.